# Lucene Search doesn't find keyword indexed fields

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, field, keyword

i save my fieldes with this code:

```
class Places_Search_Document extends Zend_Search_Lucene_Document{
public function __construct($class, $key, $title,$contents, $summary, $createdBy, $dateCreated)
    {
        $this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('docRef', "$class:$key"));
        $this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('class', $class));
        $this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('key', $key));
        $this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('title', $title ,'UTF-8'));
        $this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::unStored('contents', $contents , 'UTF-8'));
        $this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('summary', $summary , 'UTF-8'));
        //$this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('createdBy', $createdBy));
        $this->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('dateCreated', $dateCreated));
    }
```

}

i search the word with this code:

```
$index = Places_Search_Lucene::open(SearchIndexer::getIndexDirectory());
        $term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($q);
        $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard($term);
        $results = $index->find($query);
```

now it work perfect for unsorted and text fields , but it doesn`t search for keyword !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you really want those fields to be keyword analyzed? The keyword analyzer puts the whole text of the field as one token, which you rarely want.

Comment: thanx a lot for your attention :) i found my mistake ;)